# File upload difference in IE and Chrome

Tags: file-upload, file-io

I am trying to include a File Upload integration on an ASP.NET page using the HTML input control.

```
<input type="file" id="strImageName" runat="server" class="inputtxt" size="44" maxlength="100" contentEditable="false" NAME="strImageName">
```

I am accepting a variety of file types, but definitely not HTML. When I use the control:

I see two different behaviors wrt the filtered file extensions, one in IE and  the other in Chrome.
File Upload Control on IE
[image: On IE]

File Upload Control on Chrome
[image: On Chrome]

Can you please help me emulate the behavior of Chrome on IE?

Thanks,

Anil

Comment: Both screenshots show an IE icon. Also you should just check the file type serverside.

Comment: This question will presumably be closed. It is important to mention that you should ALWAYS check for file type on server, although you can almost never be 100% sure the file will be of the expected type. That's why ideally you should store uploaded files outside of the webroot and access it back with a custom handler, ensuring no one can actually execute any code server-side from an HTTP request

Comment: I have a validation available both at the server and at the client. However, its a usability issue that I am trying to address here....

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [`accept`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#Attributes) attribute ?

```
<input type="file" accept=".gif, .jpg, .png" ...>
```

Specifying the MIME-type(s) only might also work:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" ...>
```

[HTML input accept Attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#Attributes)

Comment: I am looking out at removing all and just show "All files", because I have around 15 different file types which are being accessed

Comment: @AnilVKBabu What happens if you try `accept="*/*"` or just `accept="*"`? And, are we also talking about 15 different _MIME-types_, if they are all images then the `accept="image/*"` should cover it for all of them.